# Computing a matrix from its exponential

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Given the exponential of a matrix,

$e^{At}$, what is the best way to compute A? Thinking about complex-valued 3x3 matrices here.

Comment: Is your matrix diagonalizable? Do you know $e^{tA}$ or just $e^A$?

Comment: We just know e^(tA), and is which matrix diagonalizable?

Comment: Perhaps computing the derivative at $t=0$  for $e^{tA}$ and the logarithm for $e^A$...

Comment: Do you just know $e^{tA}$ for some particular $t$, or $e^{tA}$ for all $t$?

Comment: $E^{At}$={{2,1,-1},{1,2,-1},{3,3,-2}}e^{2t}+{{-1,-1,1},{-1,-1,1},{-3,-3,3}}e^t

Comment: (your expression should be in the question) so that the derivative relatively to $t$ at $0$ will be... (you are encouraged to provide an answer yourself!)

Comment: @RaymondManzoni you are the man. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it clarified things @E.Nusinovich !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the matrix $A$ is solution of the equation $$e^{tA}=A_2\,e^{2t}+A_1\,e^t$$
and since the left and right part both admit a derivative relatively to $t$ we must have :
$$A\,e^{tA}=2\,A_2\,e^{2t}+A_1\,e^t$$
and at the limit $\,t\to 0\;$ your solution can only be $\,A=2\,A_2+A_1$.

Since it may appear rather surprising that $\;e^{\large{t\,(2\,A_2+A_1)}}=A_2\,e^{2t}+A_1\,e^{t}\;$ (as it was for me!) I had to find why this was true.

Notice that your matrices $\,A_2:=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & 2 & -1 \\
3 & 3 & -2 \end{array}\right)
$  and  $A_1:=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-1 & -1 & 1 \\
-1 & -1 & 1 \\
-3 & -3 & 3 \end{array}\right)
\;$
are rather special since verifying $\,A_1+A_2=1,\ \,A_1 A_2=A_2 A_1=0\;$ and $\,A_1^n=A_1$ and $\,A_2^n=A_2\,$ for any positive integer $n$.

From this we deduce that $\;e^{t\,A_i}=1+A_i (e^{t}-1)\;$ and for any real values $x$ and $y$ :
$$e^{\large{\,x\,A_2+y\,A_1}}=1+A_2 (e^{x}-1)+A_1 (e^{y}-1)=A_2e^x+A_1 e^y$$